# Trouble Embedding and Displaying PDF Content in Tkinter Without Rasterization

Tags: python, html, tkinter, pdf

#### Objective:

My goal is to create a Tkinter application where I can embed and display PDF content directly without rasterizing the pages. The application features a paned window with a search bar on the left and a PDF viewer on the right. I aim to preserve interactive elements within the PDF.

#### Approaches Tried and Their Issues:

1. **Using tkPDFViewer2 and pymupdf (fitz):**

   - Libraries attempted, such as tkPDFViewer2 and pymupdf, utilize pixmap to display a screenshot of the page, preventing interaction with text as in a standard PDF viewer.
2. **Embedding PDF using HTML:**

   - Tried various libraries including TkinterWeb, tkhtmlview, tkinterhtml, webview.
   - Issues with `<iframe>`, `<object>`, or `<embed>` tags.
   - `<iframe>` displays base64-encoded content, not the PDF.
   - `<object>` and `<embed>` tags result in no visible content.

#### Code Sample:

##### Using tkPDFViewer2:

```py
def display_pdf(self, pdf_path):
    self.pdf_viewer = tkPDFViewer.ShowPdf()
    temp = self.pdf_viewer.pdf_view(self.canvas_pdf, pdf_location=open(pdf_path, "r"))
    temp.pack(pady=0, padx=0, expand=True, fill="both")
```

##### Embedding PDF using HTML:

```py
def display_pdf(self, pdf_path):
    # Create a temporary HTML file to embed the PDF viewer
    temp_html_path = "/temp_viewer.html"
    with open(pdf_path, "rb") as pdf_file:
        pdf_content_base64 = base64.b64encode(pdf_file.read()).decode("utf-8")
    with open(temp_html_path, "w") as html_file:
        html_file.write(f"""
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        </head>
        <body>
            <h3>PDF Viewer</h3>
            <!-- Include various iframe, object, and embed tags -->
        </body>
        </html>
        """)
    self.frame = tkinterweb.HtmlFrame(self.canvas)
    self.frame.load_file(f"{temp_html_path}")
    self.frame.pack(fill="both", expand=True)
```

## Question:

How can I successfully embed and display PDF content inside a Tkinter application? I'm looking for a solution that allows searching for text extracted from an image within the PDF, similar to a standard PDF viewer.

## Additional Context:

- Open to alternative solutions or libraries.
- The application will be used on Windows 10 or 11 desktops and converted to a .exe file, so the suggested solution must work in a freeze state.

I appreciate any insights, suggestions, or guidance on resolving this issue. Thank you!

Comment: will it work in tkinter because my html with embed pdf works if i run it directly in the browser it doesn't work if i use in tkinter only basic tags are shown correctly is there any way i can make a desktop application and  it runs on browser without internet connection or bundling chromium etc